# Solving a boundary-value recurrence relation

Tags: difference-equations

I would like to solve a recurrence relation of the form

```
RSolve[
 {
   h[n] == p[n]*h[n + 1] + q[n]*h[n - 1] + (1 - p[n] - q[n])*h[n]
  ,h[1] == 0.5
  ,h[Nn]==0.5*h[Nn-1]
 }, h[n], n]
```

where `Nn` is some boundary condition. This runs and produces a solution, but it doesn't understands that the `Nn` is the upper bound for `n`, how can I supply this constraint?

Comment: What difference does it make if `Nn` is upper or not upper if Mma gives answer for all values of n?

Comment: I can swap 'Nn' in when I see n in the answer indeed, but perhaps a neater formula would be spit out with fixing the boundary